# How to customize firebase push notification in ionic 4?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I used cordova fcm plugin to show push notifications.I need push notification with buttons like whatsapp and facebook push notifications.Is there any way to add buttons in fcm push notifications? If not, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can do it with FCM. The concept is to set up `actions` within the `data` part of the payload:

- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#action-buttons

Structured like this:

```
{
  "registration_ids": ["my device id"],
  "data": {
    "title": "AUX Scrum",
    "message": "Scrum: Daily touchbase @ 10am Please be on time so we can cover everything on the agenda.",
    "actions": [
      {
        "icon": "emailGuests",
        "title": "EMAIL GUESTS",
        "callback": "emailGuests",
        "foreground": true
      },
      {
        "icon": "snooze",
        "title": "SNOOZE",
        "callback": "snooze",
        "foreground": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What code do you have already for your FCM push notification sending? What library are you using?

Comment: nothing happend with this code. I am using cordova fcm plugin for push notification. It shows notification only with "notification" not with "data".

Comment: { 
 "to": "/topics/global",
"notification": {
    "title": "Test title",
   "body": "Test body 2.",
  "sound": "default",
  "tag": "1",
  "color": "black"
 }
}

Comment: that code was just an example from the docs, it was never going to actually work. I'm sorry, I have tried but I don't understand what you are actually using and what your sticking point is. If you can update your question with code maybe somebody can help.